# Node js app remote debugging in SAP Cloud Foundry - breakpoints not working

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I am trying to debug remotely a simple Node.js app. I have a trial account and a subaccount with API endpoint https://api.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com.

Start script uses **--inspect** option like this: `node --inspect app.js`

Node version is 8.*

SSH access enabled on both space and app, also the SSH tunnel successfully opens for the app, and I can open Chrome debugger via "chrome://inspect".

It even stops at caught exceptions in debugger if the corresponding flag is set.

The problem is that none of the break-points working in a fragment of code which is executed for sure. What do I miss?